# Is it possible to display images from other sources on your wordpress page?

Tags: wordpress, image, post, blogs

I have a lot of pictures on my homepage. Of course, this also requires a lot of disk space. Now I got the glorious idea that I don't store the images on the website, but on an external source (like Dropbox or Google Drive). There I can then also manage my own folder structure and do not have to use this stupid structure of Wordpress.

So the idea is that I can display images on my wordpress page, that are stored on an external source. Is this possible and how?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow... Unfortunately, SO is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. You should consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and rewriting your question to include some coding you've tried to show that you have put in a little effort before you came here.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can achieve that but with a little bit different approach. Since you can't get public links to the images in your Dropbox or Google Drive, you might wanna try [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) or [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) instead.